# jQuery Form Plugin Ignored when submitting form

Tags: html, ajax, forms

I created an html form which submits data to my backend when submitted. The backend then redirects the webpage and shows a json message. I would like to remain on the same page and capture that json message to show to the user. I tried doing this using AJAX forms (https://jquery-form.github.io/form/) however upon clicking the submit button, the page still redirects and the script is kind of ignored.

Script included in the head after the CSS:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/4.2.2/jquery.form.min.js" integrity="sha384-FzT3vTVGXqf7wRfy8k4BiyzvbNfeYjK+frTVqZeNDFl8woCbF0CYG6g2fMEFFo/i" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
     // wait for the DOM to be loaded
     $(function() {
       // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function
       $('#signup-form').ajaxForm(function() {
        alert("Thank you for your comment!");
       });
   });
</script>
```

The form:

```
<form id="signup-form" action="https://example-placeholder.com/api/auth/register" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group row">                    
        <div class="col">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Email" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">                    
        <div class="col">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom btn-block" id="register-button">Register</button>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <label id="submit-label" style="display: none;">Check your inbox to activate your account!</label>  
</form>
```

Response returned by backend:

```
return response()->json([
    'message' => 'Successfully created user!'
], 201);
```

Errors returned by Google Chrome:

[image]

UPDATE (To fix CORS Error):
Added the following three lines before `RewriteEngine On` in the .htaccess file of my backend:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

Comment: Looks like you need to load jquery first. (switch the order of the first 2 script references in the head of your document)

Comment: @o4ohel Thanks! :) I switched those around and removed another script which I was loading at the end in a layouts file.

Comment: @o4ohel, The alert is not showing however...

Comment: Are there any additional error messages displayed after fixing the import?

Comment: @student0495 trying other AJAX methods always results in the following error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'backend-url' from origin 'https://www.w3schools.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Added the following three lines before ```RewriteEngine On``` in the .htaccess file of my backend:

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"